# Convert ternary operator statement to normal if/elseif/else statement

Tags: javascript

I just found a pretty long ternary operator statement and have a hard time to undestand what is going on, is there a tool or script which is able to convert this into normal if/else-if/else?

```
h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
```

Comment: Yes, fingers on keyboard. i.e. manual

Comment: FWIW, they could have broken out the `x > 9 ? x : "0" +x` pattern into a function and called it `sprintf_02d(x)`.

Comment: So i guess the answer is no, there is no such tool or script

Answer (score 3):

You could use a function and add a zero if necessary.

```
function pad(n) {
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n;
    }
    return n || '00';
}

h1.textContent = pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expanded result:

```
h1.textContent = "";
if (hours){
    h1.textContent += (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours);
} else {
    h1.textContent += "00";
}
h1.textContent += ":";
if (minutes) {
    h1.textContent += (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes);
} else {
    h1.textContent += "00";
}
h1.textContent += ":";
if (seconds > 9){
    h1.textContent += seconds;
} else {
    h1.textContent += "0" + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `Array.map`, `Array.join` and "modern" ES6 *arrow function expression*:

```
var hours = 00, minutes = 35, seconds = 5,
    time = [hours, minutes, seconds].map((v) => (v > 9? v : "0"+v) || "00").join(":");

h1.textContent = time;
console.log(time);  // "00:35:05"
```

Comment: Wow nice, thanks for sharing this.